# while EOF in JAVA?

Tags: java

Following to some forums answers I'm using this:

```
    while (fileReader.nextLine() != null) {
        String line = fileReader.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

... but it throws exception at the end anyway
(Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found)

Comment: Uh oh!! You call nextLine twice!!

Comment: What type is the fileReader ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you should use `while (fileReader.hasNextLine())`

Answer (score 22):

Each call to `nextLine()` moves onto the next line, so when you are actually at the last readable line and the `while` check passes inspection, the next call to `nextLine()` will return `EOF`.

---

Perhaps you could do one of the following instead:

If `fileReader` is of type `Scanner`:

```
while ((line = fileReader.hasNextLine()) != null) {
    String line = fileReader.nextLine(); 
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

If `fileReader` is of type `BufferedReader`:

```
String line;
while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

So you're reading the current line in the while condition and saving the line in a string for later use.

Comment: I think fileReader is of class Scanner, because it's the only one in the platform API that has a `nextLine` method. That means (1) There is no method `readLine`. (2) `nextLine` never returns `null` -- your code will still throw the exception when there's nothing more to read. Trevor's answer is the right one.

Comment: You are correct, `readLine` was a typo, and I also question the OP choice of naming a variable `fileReader` when it is actually of Type `Scanner`. That leaves room for confusion as I my previous answer(which has been edited for correctness) proved.

Answer (score 2):

To read a file Scanner class is recommended.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fFileName), fEncoding);
    try {
      while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
         System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
      }
    }
    finally{
      scanner.close();
    }
```

Comment: Considering that he calls the nextLine() method, I think he IS using a Scanner object. So that is not the problem. The problem is, as others has already stated, that nextLine() is called twice in each loop iteration.

Comment: When `Scanner's constructor` throws an exception (i.e. `IllegalArgumentException`) then the underlying FileInputStream isn't closed and therefore leaking. `scanner` var should be assigned to `null` outside the try-block and Scanner-object should be created inside the try-block.

Answer (score 2):

The others told you enough about your issue with multiple calls of `readLine()`.

I just wanted to leave sth about code style:
While you see this `line =` assignement and `!= null` check together in one while condition in most examples (like @gotomanners example here) I prefer using a `for` for it.

It is much more readable in my opinion ...

```
for (String line = in.readLine(); line != null; line = in.readLine()) {
    ...
}
```

Another nice way to write it you see in @TheCapn's example. But when you write it that way you easily see that's what a for-loop is made for.

I do not like assignments scrambled with conditions in one line. It is bad style in my opinion. But because it is so MUCH popular for that special case here to do it that way I would not consider it really bad style. (But cannot understand who established this bad style to become that popular.)

Comment: Oh man, it's friday afternoon. I didn't see it is `nextLine()` in OP's question rather than `readLine()`. :-(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're reading `nextLine()` on the while loop and THEN reading it to a variable. Not only are you getting every 2nd line printed out you're opening yourself to the exception being thrown. An example:

File:

```
Hello,
Blah blah blah,
Sincerely,
CapnStank
PS. Something something
```

On first iteration through the loop. The check on while will consume the "Hello," as not equal to null. Inside the loop body you'll see `Blah blah blah,` printed to the System.

The process will repeat with Sincerely, being consumed and Capnstank printing out.

Finally the while will consume the "PS" line while the `String line = fileReader.nextLine()` retreives an exception from the file because there's nothing further to read.

To resolve the issue:

```
String line = fileReader.nextLine();

while (line != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
  line = fileReader.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

nextLine() will throw an exception when there's no line and it will never return null,you can try the Scanner Class instead : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score -1):

```
while(inFile.hasNext())
```

This is correct in java programming language

Answer (score -1):

```
//By: Ishraga Mustafa Awad Allam

import java.io.*; 
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException; 

public class B_C_Data {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        try {
        // Create a file reader
            FileInputStream fr = new   FileInputStream(args[0]);
        // Create a file output stream
            DataInputStream dr = new DataInputStream(fr);
        // Read and display data
            while (dr.available() > 0) {
              System.out.println(dr.readDouble());
            }
        // Close file input stream
            dr.close();         
            }
        catch(Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
            }
    }  
}
```