# read each 5 lines every click in a button

Tags: java, file

I have a text file that consists of several entries such as:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
```

The text file contains 100 lines and I want to read each 5 lines in a once. I have this code but it give null values:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
String sCurrentLine;
int lines = 0;
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new          
    FileReader("/users/MoathIbrahem/Desktop/Questions.txt"));
    while(br.readLine()!= null)lines++;
        for(int i = 0;i < lines;i++)
            System.out.println(br.readLine());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because when you read a line a reader pointer advances. When you try to read in the for loop this pointer has reached the end of the document.

I recommend you to not count the lines before. Like the user [gotomanners](https://stackoverflow.com/users/184646/gotomanners) says in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270926/while-eof-in-java):

```
String line;
while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null)   {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
but how the loop will be if i want to read every 5 lines in a once?

Comment: Use a counter variable like: int currentLines = 0

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
while(br.readLine()!= null)lines++;
```

you are going to read ALL of the text file.

Nothing more to read unless you re-open the File or use `mark/reset`